# What causes error: "Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame. Check your code, or increase the Clock.max_iteration attribute" in Kivy?

Tags: python, android, kivy-language, kivymd, mobile-development

I'm still learning and I'm getting an error *Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame. Check your code, or increase the Clock.max_iteration attribute. *

```
BoxLayout:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: area_img.size
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}    
        Court:
            id: area_img
            source: 'half-court.png'
            size: self.texture_size
        
        MDBottomNavigation:
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: "btnSave"
                text: "Save"
                icon: "images/save.png"
                selected_color_background: 147/255,84/255,48/255
                on_tab_release: root.show_save()
    
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: "btnClear"
                text: "Clear Screen"
                icon: "images/clear.png"
                selected_color_background: 147/255,84/255,48/255
                on_tab_release: root.clear_drawing()
    
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: "btnBack"
                text: "Home"
                icon: "images/home.png"
                selected_color_background: 147/255,84/255,48/255
                # on_tab_release: app.root.current = 'main'
```

I'm trying to include the MDBottomNavigation to the screen so I can save, clear the output of the data and can easily go back to home screen. This is my kv file. Without the MDBottomNavigation it's working well, but when I include it, that's the error being said.

[How it looks like with MDBottomNavigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqFtQ.png)
[Without](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z52QR.png)

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: @ApuCoder Hi, it's been solved. I just moved the MDBottomNavigation before the BoxLayout. and added a z index to the Court and MDBottomNavigation, so the bottomnavigation can be behind the court image